# Каковы границы причастного оборота в предложении?

Tags: причастный-оборот

> Тускло белел снег, за ночь успевший запорошить и старую листву, и
> остатки костра, и пни, и упавшие деревья.

Сначала выделила здесь как причастный оборот всё, что идёт после слов "за ночь", но сейчас как-то в ступоре. Вроде идут однородные дополнения дальше, но как тогда выделить границы у этого причастного оборота по-другому?.. Мне кажется, просто "за ночь успевший запорошить" выделять странно.

Answer (score 1):

*Тускло белел снег, **за ночь успевший запорошить и старую листву, и остатки костра, и пни, и упавшие деревья.***

Причастный оборот — это причастие в полной форме с зависимыми словами.
В этом предложении причастным оборотом является все, что идет после существительного "снег". Это определяемое слово, от которого и ставится вопрос "какой?".

Сочетание "успевший запорошить" — главное в причастном обороте, от него и задаются "внутренние" вопросы:
успевший запорошить — когда? — за ночь;
успевший запорошить — что? — листву, остатки костра, пни, деревья.

Конструкция интересна тем, что внутри причастного оборота имеется одиночное причастие "упавшие" (деревья — какие? — упавшие).
Вполне вероятно, что при определении границ это и смущало.

Для проверки причастный оборот можно заменить придаточным определительным:
*Тускло белел снег, **который** за ночь **успел запорошить** и старую листву, и остатки костра, и пни, и упавшие деревья.*

Вот похожий пример (с однородными членами):
*Сад, **успевший побывать королевским огородом, королевским же парком для прогулок и луна-парком,** теперь работает национальным книгохранилищем* (Григорий Гольденцвайг. Стокгольм).

[Что такое причастный оборот?](https://russkiiyazyk.ru/chasti-rechi/glagol/prichastie/prichastnyiy-oborot.html)

Answer (score 0):

Границы причастного оборота в данном предложении:

```
"успевший запорошить и старую листву, и остатки костра, и пни, и упавшие деревья."
```

> Причастный оборот - это группа слов, которая определяет или дополняет
> глагол или существительное.

В данном предложении "успевший запорошить и старую листву, и остатки костра, и пни, и упавшие деревья" определяет снег. Это группа слов образует причастный оборот, который находится между глаголом "белел" и названием существительное снег.

Таким образом, границы причастного оборота в данном предложении: "успевший запорошить и старую листву, и остатки костра, и пни, и упавшие деревья."

"за ночь" тоже может быть причастным оборотом, так как оно определяет глагол "успевший" и сообщает, что действие произошло за ночь. В данном случае оно и есть причастным оборотом.

Таким образом, предложение будет иметь следующий вид:

```
"Тускло белел снег, за ночь, успевший запорошить и старую листву, и остатки костра, и пни, и упавшие деревья."
```

Comment: Evgeny, Ваш ответ неверный. Пересмотрите, пожалуйста, свои представления о причастном обороте.